# How to access json fields with Jolt Transform?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

How do I access json fields with Jolt transform?

For example I have this json:

```json
{
  "a": 110,
  "b": 10
}
```

I would like to have:

```json
{
  "a": 110,
  "b": 10,
  "c": 100   // 110 - 10 (substraction)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following transformation will add a `c` variable which is set to `a - b`:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "a": "a",
      "b": "b"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c": "=intSubtract(@(1,a), @(1,b))"
    }
  }
]
```

If you wish to test it, the [Jolt demo website](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) is an excellent resource. Put your original JSON into the "JSON Input" box:

```json
{
  "a": 110,
  "b": 10
}
```

Then place the transformation spec from the top of this answer into the "JOLT Spec" box and hit the <kbd>Transform</kbd> button. The result should be as you desired:

```json
{
  "a" : 110,
  "b" : 10,
  "c" : 100
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of  "1" in "@(1,a)"?
There is documentation about this?

Comment: @Ran, it means to walk up the tree that many levels and look up the `a` value starting at that level. Given your input JSON is fairly simple (not many hierarchical levels), there's not much scope for using different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You just can use a single **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation along with a **intSubtract** function in order to add add an extra element to the current json value such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c": "=intSubtract(@(1,a),@(1,b))"
    }
  }
]
```